# Accessing ajax response object once complete

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to set the `search` ajax response to the `query` variable **only** once the request is complete. However, I am getting an undefined alert. I was wondering if someone knows how to accomplish this goal?

I appreciate any advice,

Many thanks in advance!

```
    var query ='';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "ajax/search.php?&reqPage="+reqPage,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success: function(search){
            $('.search-table').html(search.rows);           
        },
        complete: function(search){
            query = search.query;
            alert(query); //output undefined
        },
        error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }
    });
```

Comment: First, use `console.log` in place of `alert`. Second, try logging `search` instead of `search.query`. It may be that `search` is undefined as well. If so that would indicate that your URL is bad.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First, I prefer `alert` as it does not keep me from accomplishing my goal. The `search` response is **not** undefined, because the `html` is coming through from the `search.rows`. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: Also, `search.query` **is** defined if I access it inside the `success` clause, however, I need to access it outside of the success clause **only** when ajax request is done.

Comment: When the `search` variable in the `success` function contains rows does not automatically mean that `search` is also defined in the `complete` function

Comment: @Rick, this is exactly my question :) I **know** it is not defined inside the **complete** function. I am trying to get help figuring out why it **is** defined in the `success` function, but not in the `complete` function.

Comment: Using `console.log` prevents you from accomplishing your goal? How? Second, the `search` variable in your `success` function is different from the one in your `complete` function. `complete` receives a `jqXHR` object, not the actual data. Take a look at the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) page, specifically the `complete` function.

Comment: You misread my comment, I said using alerts **does not** prevent me from accomplishing my goal. In other words, I prefer it. Recommending I use `console.log` does not get me any closer to a solution than using `alerts` :)

Comment: You insinuated it by saying that `alert` doesn't prevent you from accomplishing your goal. But that's besides the fact--`console.log` will provide you with a vast amount of information regarding the object itself. If you log `search`, for example, it won't just log `[object Object]`. It'll return all the properties of that object. It would have shown you, for example, that `complete` receives a `jqXHR` object, not the `data` from the AJAX call.

Answer (score 2):

First of complete callback in jquery gives 2 arguments in. And there is no data, only jqXHR and textStatus. Because complete callback calls in error. So Your code should be:

```
var query ='';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "ajax/search.php?&reqPage="+reqPage,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success: function(search){
        $('.search-table').html(search.rows);           
        query = search.query;
    },
    error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }
});
```

It would be called when request is compelte and no server errors. And in your case answer is valid JSON object.
Data isnt passed in complete callback because error may not pass an answer.

Comment: This is how it was before. However, `query` is undefined at the time I try to use it, because the request is not complete by the time I try to use it.

Comment: It`s impossible. $.ajax is facade for xmlhttprequest object. And it calls it callbacks only when readystate is complete. So if you returning from server this field it should be there. Otherwise look at you php code.

Comment: Flops is correct. You must not be returning `query` as part of the data.

Comment: Something else must be the issue then. Complete does not return your data. It is available in success. Try using the new methods available to you such as done in place of success and see what happens... Like others have now said, query must not be getting returned.

Comment: Okay, I will investigate and report back. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Nice catch! it turned out to be a PHP issue!